# Schwartz-Cristoffel Integral from $\mathbb{D}$ to a regular polygon

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $F(z) = \int_1^x \frac{dt}{(1-t^n)^{2/n}}$.  I want to show that $F$ maps $\mathbb{D}$, the open unit disc, to a regular polygon with $n$ sides.

My approach thus far has been to show that (similar to the Schwartz-Cristoffel integral from $\mathbb{H}$ to polygons), that functions from $\mathbb{D}$ to polygons are of the form $\int_1^z \frac{dt}{(t-B_1)^{\beta_1}\ldots (t-B_n)^{\beta_n}}$.  I'm not sure how to modify this to get the above formula, however.

Moreover, I would like to show that the perimeter of the polygon that this function creates is $2^\frac{n-2}{n} \int_o^{\pi} (\sin \theta)^{\frac{-2}{n}} d\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Over complex numbers, every polynomial factors into linear terms. In particular, 
$$t^n-1 = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(t-\zeta^k),\qquad \zeta=e^{2\pi i/n}$$ 
This should tell you how to put $F$ into the Schwarz-Cristoffel form.

The perimeter of the image can be calculated as the limit of lengths of $f(|z|=r)$ as $r\to1$. This yields
$$L=\lim_{r\to 1^-} \int_0^{2\pi} |F'(re^{i\theta})|\,d\theta $$ 
But here $F'$ is continuous up to the boundary (except at finitely many points, at which the singularity is not too bad). So, the limit passes into the integral:
$$L= \int_0^{2\pi} |F'( e^{i\theta})|\,d\theta $$ 
Since you know $F'(z)=(1-z^n)^{-2/n}$, the rest should not be too hard.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.  I'm still having a bit of trouble getting the expression for the perimeter into the form of the original problem.  I'm guessing there's a clever change of variables, but a hint would be appreciated.